# White strap at bottom of page

Tags: html, wordpress, css

On this [website](http://www.roomstonite.com/) I see the white strap at the bottom can anyone help on this ?
this website is powerd by wordpress

Comment: This question could be improved by stating the expected result. You want the white space to disappear, right? Then say so. Also, include whatever you have tried and why your attempts didn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being caused by this `iframe`:

```
<iframe name="google_conversion_frame" ...>
```

You could add an inline style like:

```
<iframe name="google_conversion_frame" style="display: none;" ...>
```

or use CSS

```
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually just inspect the white strap with the "Inspect Element" on the browser if you see a white color just untick it and than find it in the css file and remove it,but i don't see a white strap on the bottom i only see a white strap under the slideshow which is this

```
.vc_custom_1429248247553{
padding-top: 30px !important;
background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Open your CSS file in a text editor ctrl + F and search for `.vc_custom_1429248247553` and than remove both

```
padding-top: 30px !important;
background-color: #ffffff !important;
```

Comment: one  can clearly see white space at the bottom of the page and it's not beacause of the background-color. Bad catch..

Comment: the only way that i can see a white space under the site if i zoom out to 50% otherwise i don't see any stripe and i don't know why anyone would zoom out to 50%